# AzCopy - how to upload single file to a container using SAS

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I have a SAS for container (WRITE only, but I tries READ-WRITE-LIST too). And I need to upload a single file to that container. So I use AzCopy for that:

```
AzCopy /Source:./ /Dest:https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container/?sv=2018-03-28&si=write&sr=c&sig=****** /Pattern:somefile.ext /V:./AzCopy.log
```

And I tried another version:

```
AzCopy /Source:somefile.ext /Dest:https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container/somefile.ext /DestSAS:******
```

but that doesn't work either.

And I tried both AzCopy versions - 7.1.3 and 8.1! What else should I try?

BTW, with Powershell it works like a charm, with the same SAS token!
Windows 10 latest.

**UPDATE**

The log (made on completely different machine):

> [2019.03.22 06:39:41.551+03:00] >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> [2019.03.22
>   06:39:41.561+03:00][VERBOSE] Finished: 0 file(s), 0 B; Average Speed:0
>   B/s. [2019.03.22 06:39:41.569+03:00][VERBOSE] 8.1.0 : AzCopy
>   /Source:somefile.ext
>   /Dest:https://account.blob.core.windows.net/korch/somefile.ext
>   /DestSAS:****** /V:./AzCopy with SAS.log [2019.03.22
>   06:39:41.589+03:00][ERROR] An error occurred while reading the restart
>   journal from "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Azure\AzCopy".
>   Detailed error: Error parsing the journal file: Journal file was
>   generated by a different version of AzCopy. [2019.03.22
>   06:39:43.175+03:00][VERBOSE] [PROMPT] Do you want to overwrite the
>   journal to start a new operation? Choose Yes to overwrite, choose No
>   to cancel current operation. (Yes/No) : Y [2019.03.22
>   06:39:43.230+03:00][VERBOSE] Attempt to parse address 'somefile.ext'
>   to a directory as a candidate location succeeded. [2019.03.22
>   06:39:43.232+03:00][VERBOSE] Attempt to parse address 'somefile.ext'
>   to a single file as a candidate location succeeded. [2019.03.22
>   06:39:43.239+03:00][VERBOSE] Source is interpreted as a Local file:
>   G:\1\somefile.ext. [2019.03.22 06:39:43.260+03:00][VERBOSE] Attempt to
>   parse address
>   'https://account.blob.core.windows.net/korch/somefile.ext' to a
>   directory as a candidate location succeeded. [2019.03.22
>   06:39:43.269+03:00][VERBOSE] Attempt to parse address
>   'https://account.blob.core.windows.net/korch/somefile.ext' to a single
>   file as a candidate location succeeded. [2019.03.22
>   06:39:43.270+03:00][VERBOSE] Interpreting destination as a single file
>   as the provided source is a single file. [2019.03.22
>   06:39:43.271+03:00][VERBOSE] Destination is interpreted as a Cloud
>   blob: https://account.blob.core.windows.net/korch/somefile.ext.
>   [2019.03.22 06:39:43.942+03:00][VERBOSE] Start transfer:
>   G:\1\somefile.ext =>
>   https://account.blob.core.windows.net/korch/somefile.ext [2019.03.22
>   06:39:44.149+03:00][VERBOSE] Transfer FAILED: G:\1\somefile.ext =>
>   https://account.blob.core.windows.net/korch/somefile.ext. [2019.03.22
>   06:39:44.158+03:00][ERROR] An unknown error occurred: The transfer
>   failed. Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value
>   of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
>   HttpStatusMessage:Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure
>   the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the
>   signature. RequestId:76ffafce-901e-0132-6460-e00b82000000 Time:Fri, 22
>   Mar 2019 06:39:44 GMT [2019.03.22 06:39:44.161+03:00] Transfer
>   summary:
>   ----------------- Total files transferred: 1 Transfer successfully:   0 Transfer skipped:        0 Transfer failed:         1 Elapsed time: 
>   00.00:00:02

Comment: You need to specify the SAS for the source also ?

Comment: source is the local file!

Comment: What's the error message you're getting?

Comment: Unauthorized header.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include complete error message? I tried both commands you used above and I was able to successfully upload a local file.

Comment: added the log file contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I created a .CMD file for AzCopy'ing a single file. But I didn't know I had to escape % in windows batch files. That's why SAS token was not correct at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I tried that worked.

```
AzCopy /Source:D:\temp /Dest:https://account-name.blob.core.windows.net/blob-container-name /DestSAS:"?se=2019-03-30T18%3A30%3A00Z&sp=rw&sv=2018-03-28&sr=c&sig=xxxxx...%3D" /Pattern:test.txt

AzCopy /Source:D:\temp2 /Dest:"https://account-name.blob.core.windows.net/blob-container-name?se=2019-03-30T18%3A30%3A00Z&sp=rw&sv=2018-03-28&sr=c&sig=xxxxx...%3D" /Pattern:test.log
```

One thing I noticed is that if I just include `Write` permission, the operation fails. I had to add `Read` permission in my SAS for the operation to succeed.

Furthermore, I had to include SAS token in double quotes.

Comment: Are you sure your SAS token made with policy *for the container*?

Comment: I did not use a policy. I created an ad-hoc SAS token with read and write permission on the blob container.

Comment: ok, I think I found the problem. I made a .cmd file with parameter and SAS token should be escaped inside batch file... Gr....!

Comment: Awesome! Please include your solution as an answer. It might help some other folks who’re using the command file approach.